# unzip cannot delete directory in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

This is what I'm getting when I run AWS terraform plan with Jenkins. Below code that we are using

Error: error:  cannot delete old terraform
            Is a directory

Code : 
    sh '''set +x
    curl -L 'https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.11.10/terraform_0.11.10_linux_amd64.zip' --output terraform.zip
    unzip -o terraform.zip
    echo "Using $(terraform -version) from: $(which terraform)"
    '''
    sh "terraform init -backend-config='bucket=${bucketName}'"

Jenkins Error:

```
+ set +x
after terraform download
Archive:  terraform.zip
error:  cannot delete old terraform
        Is a directory
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 50
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please suggest some better solution.

Comment: There is an unzip method for Pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Unzip refuses to overwrite the `terraform/` directory that seems to be still lying around in your workspace from the previous run.

Run either a `sh "rm -rf terraform/"` before the `unzip` (or `cleanWs()`)

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a directory named "terraform" containing your terraform files. Then it conflicts with the file "terraform" that is contained in the ZIP archive. That's why unzip fails.

Answer (score -1):

```
unzip -f terraform.zip
```

Use -f instead of -o

```
-f  freshen existing files, create none i.e unzip to replace the new files only
-n  never overwrite existing files         
-q  quiet mode (-qq => quieter)
-o  overwrite files WITHOUT prompting
```